# Google Analytics Module

Tags: drupal

This is not a programming problem!

I have been using the drupal site for years now and today I need a module:

https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics

when the site loads I don't see the usual download links. Please look at it and tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Download link should be their:

[image]

Wait... it will be solved in a couple of hours certainly. If you need it ASAP you can use git and [clone the repository](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics/git-instructions).